# Does the YouTube API have a webhook or a socket? Notify me when there is a new comment? [cerrada]

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I have developed a program with the youtube api that get all the live chat (Message in live of youtube)

Now, I am looking for that every time there is a new message in the live chat,

This is because I want to create a bot so that when someone puts "Twitter!" the bot responds with my twitter.

Since I couldn't find a stream of the new messages, what I did was get the messages. And then get them back in 10 seconds. And then select the messages that you had not obtained before

Comment: Did you ever find solution to this? Seems like listening to messages live by REST exhausts the 10,000 daily credit pretty quick...